# connecting from spring-boot to PostgreSQL replica

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

We just set  up a PostgreSQL replica (master-slave).
We also setup repmgr for automatic failover.

Our application is using spring-boot.

If the master fails, we need the application to connect transparently to the current primary (previously standby).

How can we set this up in the connection string?

Answer (score 4):

This format worked:
jdbc:postgresql://host1:port1,host2:port2/database